# Is it ok to use one viewholder for two view type?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am new to android development , I want to create a recycler view with two view type one for video and another for photo ,but Is it necessary to create 2 Viewholder for that , can't  we Just use one Viewholder for that ?? Cause I am facing lot of problem like I need to declare this function two times for 2 viewholder

**FOR PhotoHolder**

```
private void addNewlike(final PhotoHolder holder){
    Log.d(TAG, "addNewlike: adding new like ");
    String newLikeID = mReference.push().getKey();
    Likes likes = new Likes();
    likes.setUser_id(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    mReference.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_photos))
            .child(holder.photo.getPhoto_id())
            .child(mContext.getString(R.string.field_likes))
            .child(newLikeID)
            .setValue(likes);
    mReference.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_user_photos))
            .child(holder.photo.getUser_id())
            .child(holder.photo.getPhoto_id())
            .child(mContext.getString(R.string.field_likes))
            .child(newLikeID)
            .setValue(likes);
    holder.heart.toggleLike();
    HashMap<String ,String> notificationData = new HashMap<>();
    notificationData.put("from",FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    notificationData.put("type","likes");
    notificationData.put("photo_desc",holder.photo.getDescription());

    holder.mNotification.child(holder.photo.getUser_id()).setValue(notificationData).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            getLikesString(holder);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            getLikesString(holder);


        }
    });

}
```

**FOR VideoHolder**

```
private void addNewlike(final VideoHolder holder){
    Log.d(TAG, "addNewlike: adding new like ");
    String newLikeID = mReference.push().getKey();
    Likes likes = new Likes();
    likes.setUser_id(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    mReference.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_photos))
            .child(holder.photo.getPhoto_id())
            .child(mContext.getString(R.string.field_likes))
            .child(newLikeID)
            .setValue(likes);
    mReference.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_user_photos))
            .child(holder.photo.getUser_id())
            .child(holder.photo.getPhoto_id())
            .child(mContext.getString(R.string.field_likes))
            .child(newLikeID)
            .setValue(likes);
    holder.heart.toggleLike();
    HashMap<String ,String> notificationData = new HashMap<>();
    notificationData.put("from",FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    notificationData.put("type","likes");
    notificationData.put("photo_desc",holder.photo.getDescription());

    holder.mNotification.child(holder.photo.getUser_id()).setValue(notificationData).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            getLikesString(holder);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            getLikesString(holder);


        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest having a single custom ViewHolder, have a variable set in that viewholder for which “type” it is, and then when you’re drawing using the viewholder just wrap the photo adjustments in a if(isPhoto) { // do all work with photos } else { // do all work with videos

Comment: only with one view holder with two view type, does it as disadvantage ??THANKS for your answer

Comment: The only disadvantage would be if the views were to be extremely different and complicated, meaning you would need to “clump” a lot of code into a single viewholder object making it unnecessarily verbose, so if they’re two very simple views then it wouldn’t be a problem, but if you’re planning to have very detailed views showing a lot of information then I would advice splitting them into seperate viewholders or at least work on making the code cleaner and easier to read

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,Cause this is what is needed

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you declare a common view holder class and the you extend this class for photoHolder and VideoHolder?

You need a common class:

```
public class MediaHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

// common properties

}
```

and then extend this class for your photoHolder and VideoHolder.

Then you should declare your your method like this:

```
private void addNewlike(final MediaHolder holder)
```

Comment: I have done that using abstract class it returns null and also what about the Image view and other items I wanna get ,I dont know